# gnome-terminal not working because of signal 11

Tags: c, signals, gnome-terminal

I am working on a C project and I want to launch several C programs in different terminals from one main C program.
More explicitly, I have a **game.c** program which setup several parameters such as the number of players, the rules, etc. This program has to open *n* terminals and has to run a **player.c** program in each terminal in order to able each of the *n* players to configure their avatars.

Here is the problem : I am using     system("gnome-terminal -e ./player args")     in order to open the terminals **BUT** even if the terminals successfully open, it does not run the program and a notification appears indicating that the program has been aborted due to "Signal 11". It looks like this Signal 11 can not be ignored.

Do you know a way to solve this problem (if it is possible) ? Modify a .conf file ? Use an other commande than gnome-terminal ?

En vous souhaitant une bonne journée,
Peyret

Comment: Signal 11 is caused by a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). This has very little to do with the terminal itself or any `.conf` files. You need to fix your code instead

Comment: the source of the problem is the ,/player application.  Post the source code.  Most likely there is some 'wild' pointer or other undefined behavior.

Comment: since `system()` does not return until the called program returns, I'm thinking we are not getting the full story.  My first suggestion is to start the terminal program via a call to fork() than in the child process, call one of the `exec..()` functions to invoke the terminal program, with the appropriate parameters to run the ./player application